# Better way to avoid casting?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, casting, implementation

I have interface Foo

```
public interface Foo {
    public void test();
}
```

Class FooChild implements interface Foo.

```
public class FooChild implements Foo {

    @Override
    public void test() {...}

    public void test2() {...}
}
```

I have to call function test2 in somewhere in the code.

```
Foo f = new FooChild();
((FooChild) f).test2();
```

I really hate casting an interface to a class.

So I added another interface Bar.

```
public interface Bar extends Foo {
    public void test2();
}

public class FooChild implements Bar {

    @Override
    public void test() {...}

    @Override
    public void test2() {...}
}
```

Now I call test2() with casting to an interface, not a class.

```
Foo f = new FooChild();
((Bar) f).test2();
```

I may add function test2 to the interface Foo,
but there are too many classes that implement Foo.

If I add the function, I have to add codes to all the classes that implement Foo.

Although I can do that above, I actually don't have permission to edit Foo.

Will there be any fancier way to solve this problem? (hopefully without casting)

EDIT:
f is passed as a method parameter.

As Jon said, I should have be more specific.
Sorry for the confusion.

```
public void doSomething(Foo f) {
...
}
```

Comment: without knowing the "reason" behind the examples, it's pretty hard to give any meaningful feedback.  e.g. why is test2 only on the subclass?

Comment: I assume you can't switch over to another language like javascript?

Comment: f comes from function's argument, Foo f. I cannot edit the function's argument so as to make the argument either `Bar` or `FooChild`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know that the variable value really *has* to be of type `FooChild`, just declare it that way:

```
FooChild f = new FooChild();
f.test2();
```

If there's some reason why that won't work for you, it's something you haven't told us...

EDIT: Okay, so apparently it's really a method parameter:

```
public void doSomething(Foo f) {
    ((FooChild) f).test2();
}
```

... so no, there's nothing you can do to avoid the cast. The cast indicates that there's a requirement on the value beyond what the declared variable type already guarantees - in this case, you want to say "It's got to actually be a `FooChild`, not just any implementation of `Foo`." Casts are *the* way of expressing that, if you can't change the parameter.

Comment: Actually f comes from function's argument, Foo f. So, I cannot do something like this.

Comment: @Heejin: In that case you're going to *have* to cast - because you're relying on something which *isn't* known to be correct at compile-time. (And please, next time give more representative code. Your sample code showed you declaring a local variable and instantiating `FooChild` yourself. Apparently that isn't the case, so your sample code should have reflected that - you should have shown it as a parameter.)

Comment: if the function "doSomething" relies on the method "test2" you should consider changing the method signature to an interface or class, that supports "test2".
This may result in casts or checks at positions calling doSomething.

Answer (score 5):

```
Bar f = new FooChild();
f.test2();
```

Comment: this is the RIGHT way in my opinion. If one needs a method of a interface A - one uses interface A (not B cast to A etc.) +1

Comment: This is also largely harmless, since Bar extends Foo you can use this object f in any method which accepts Foo, but others are free to write Foo objects which do not have the test2 method.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what you exactly want here, but you could possibly create a helper function for any Foo objects to return a FooChild..

```
public FooChild getImpl(Foo input){
  if (input instanceof FooChild){
    return (FooChild)input;
  }else{
    return null;
  }
}
```

that way you call your helper function like so (assuming not null:

```
getImpl(f).test2();
```

Note: this code does not check for nulls at all, which you would need to do in your code.